# How does Mongo Query works?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I like to know the internal process of how mongo query works. I had gone through the source code of Mongo. But, I could not find the right way to understand it.

**Mongo Query 1:**

```
db.collection.find({
    class : 10,
    subject:"Physics",
    name :"John Doe"
});
```

**Mongo Query 2:**

```
db.collection.find({
    name :"John Doe",
    class : 10,
    subject:"Physics",
});
```

Consider a scenario, in a collection, if the name value -"John Doe" occurs only twice and class value - 10 occurs hundred times, will the second query executes faster or will both queries take same response time. Is the order of query matters?

Comment: Possible dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18179500/mongodb-and-mongoose-js-does-the-order-of-query-conditions-matter

Answer (score 1):

Its all depends on `index`, MongoDB will give preferences for Indexed key at first.

You can use [Explain](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/meta/explain/) which gives results that you want such as how many records have been processed to get this result, is there any index key in your query.

I love using [Compass](https://www.mongodb.com/products/compass) Which gives explains query visually.

Comment: Explain() is really cool.. Let me go through it before writing compound queries. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Happy to help you :) Please accept the answer that really helped you.